# Launch GUI to view current directory from command line?

Tags: raspbian, bash

I just installed Raspbian on a Pi 3 and I am having a lot of fun with it. One thing has me stymied, though:

On Mac OS, if you're in the bash Terminal, you can enter:

```
open .
```

and this will launch Finder (the graphical file manager) on the current directory. Of course you could also enter `open ~` or `open /path/to/some/other/dir`.

On the Windows command line, you can enter `start .` to launch Windows explorer on the current directory, or `start c:\some\other\directory` etc.

What's the equivalent command in stock Raspbian?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not really RasPi specific and just depends on your OS / it's installed file manager.

For Raspbian, that should be pcmanfm
So `pcmanfm .`

Comment: And you can also run it via sudo if you want to play around in the guts with full permissions.

Comment: **Thanks!** I'm mildly surprised that it's a matter of just entering the name of the file manager; Mac OS and Windows add one layer of indirection.